# Increase size of SplitContainerControl split bar

Tags: .net, user-interface, devexpress, splitcontainer

I am using a SplitContainerControl which has two panels. I'd like to increase the size of the splitter drag panel between them because it's difficult to see and click/drag. Is there a property that controls this? I can see SplitterBounds but it's readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new skin. I found it pretty easy.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#SkinEditor/CustomDocument2547

Answer (score 1):

`splitContainer1.SplitterWidth = 100;`

.NET also has a standalone splitter bar (without panels like SplitContainer); its width can be changed in the form editor.  The slight trick with standalone splitter is setting the docking order.

EDIT: O.P. had revised to show that he's working with DevExpress SplitContainerControl rather than .NET native SplitContainer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed my implementation to SplitContainterControl, but upvoted your answer because it's still correct :)